# Use of commas around 'though'

Tags: oxford-comma

With regard to the use of commas around 'though', which of the following is correct or deemed more appropriate?
'It is interesting, though, as I've done a lot of work in...'
'It is interesting though, as I've done a lot of work in...'
'It is interesting though as I've done a lot of work in...'

Comment: Commas are meant for readability, they're not part of grammar. They can be dispensed with where there's no possibility of ambiguity or loss of readability.

Answer (score 2):

In this instance, commas should be used either side of "though" (as in your first example), because it is an aside. However, this is not always the case. For instance, when the word is used to mean "despite", such as, "She was curious, though she had no reason to be."

Comment: Thanks, Colin. That agrees my thinking; namely that 'though' in this case is effectively in parenthesis. It just looks clumsy, wait for it...though.

Comment: I am not with the *should* part of it. See also my comment at OP.